# Registry setting for Internet Explorer's "Compatibility View settings" to add a site?

Tags: windows-registry

We've got one single site (intranet site) that doesn't play well with Internet Explorer 10 **unless** we add it to Internet Explorer's *"Compatibility View Settings"*. So if you open Internet Explorer and go to the menu *Tools* -> *Compatibility View settings* you get a pop up menu like so:

[image]

If I add the intranet site all is well. However, we need to add this site to everyone's machine in the company. What is the registry key / value I can use so I can add it to our startup script? If you can point me to the registry key then this would save so much time rather than going to each end user PC and doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

URL’s can be added to Compatibility View List in IE 10 by using the following group policy,

*User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Internet Explorer->Compatibility View->Use Policy List of Internet Explorer 7 sites.*

If you want to enter this information directly in the registry,

1. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\PolicyList (You may create registry folders manually if not present, or a **.REG** file will create everything for you)
2. Right Click PolicyList ->New->String Value->Enter the name of the website both under ‘Name’ and ‘Data’ (e.g. superuser.com)

Example REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\PolicyList]
"superuser.com"="superuser.com"
```

Answer (score 4):

This didn't work with my system. I did find what it did, but not easy to create. One would have to add it to a Compatibility View list and export it from the below area.

Mine created a binary key named "UserFilter" in the following path:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData

For the example of superuser.com it create the below entry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData]
"UserFilter"=hex:41,1f,00,00,53,08,ad,ba,01,00,00,00,38,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,\
  01,00,00,00,0c,00,00,00,b4,74,d2,47,55,3a,cf,01,01,00,00,00,0d,00,73,00,75,\
  00,70,00,65,00,72,00,75,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00
```

NOTE: This replaces any existing entries. It would delete them and replace all entries with ONLY this example.

Comment: (1) “This didn’t work with my system.”  *What* didn’t work with your system?  Are you commenting on another answer?  Please don’t do that, and, if you must, at least say what answer you’re talking about.  (2) Similarly, “I did find what it did, …” — you found what *what* did?  (3) What is your answer?  What do you advise the OP to do?  (Having read your post five times, I suspect that I understand.  But I’m not sure, and most people won’t read your post five times.) Please [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Hmm. I just noticed that John was a drive-by answerer — he posted this one answer, never registered and never came back.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for my IE9 and Vista.
Name should be a URL.
Data could be totally ignored or any string of charcters or, better still, your own label.

Examples:

-> Gmail does not support IE9, but works fine with IE8 and IE10, IE11:

Name = accounts.google.com

Data =

or

Data = Gmail

-> To skip Google search engine popup about "make Google default search engine":

Name = google.com

Data =

or

Data = Google w/o nuisance popup

-> For banks that insist on older IE versions:

Name = seventhnationalbank.com

Data =

or

Data = 7th Natl Bank