# Compatibility view settings for IE10 dont work for IE9?

Tags: windows-registry, internet-explorer-9

I posted this some time ago specific to IE10:

[registry setting for IE's compatibility view settings to add a site?](https://superuser.com/questions/629918/registry-setting-for-ies-compatibility-view-settings-to-add-a-site)

I have the same issue but for a pc running IE9.  The registry fix for that does not work for IE9.  Does anyone know what the registry setting is for adding a site to compatibility view settings in IE9.  See my original thread on top.

Comment: You could find out yourself: a) add a unique site, e.g. "thisisafakesite.com", b) open the program `regedit` and search for the value "thisisafakesite.com"

Comment: lol good idea, let me try that...

Comment: @medigeek Im not getting any returned results.  I added thisisafakesite.com to my IE9 compatibility view and did a search..nothing.  I rebooted and tried again and still nothing.

Comment: Have you tried setting the mode inside the html code? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915.aspx -- Better yet, why not just fix the website to be HTML5 compliant? :)