# Adding sites to Internet Explorer 11 Compatibility View list

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, internet-explorer-11

With IE10, I could add selected sites to Compatibility View via the registry with something like [registry setting for IE's compatibility view settings to add a site?](https://superuser.com/questions/629918/registry-setting-for-ies-compatibility-view-settings-to-add-a-site), so it was easy to push these settings out to my users.  But with IE11, I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.  I've done some tests and searched the registry but haven't been able to locate the correct key.

How do you add sites to Compatibility View with Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: I found multiple topics on this subject specifically for IE 11.  The first http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11_pr-windows8_1_pr/is-internet-explorer-11-missing-compatibility-mode/e178b044-82ea-4c2d-aa52-c9d9867069b4 and the second: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770933/how-can-i-programmatically-add-website-to-compatibility-list-internet-explorer-1

Comment: Unfortunately I tried these already.  I haven't yet been able to figure out where the information is stored.  I have a full system scan going on now searching for a test string that I entered into IE11.

Comment: I have personally confirmed the directions I linked to work.

Comment: Not sure if this works the same for all versions but I am using IE 11.0.9600.16428

Comment: I am only aware of two builds of IE 11.

Comment: Yeah, what I found is completely different than the GPO method (see my answer below).  Leave it to Microsoft...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specifically address the issue mentioned by STGdb regarding Exchange OWA forcing light mode. There is a patch for Exchange server for this issue.

*Can't load OWA Premium by using Internet Explorer 11 in an Exchange Server environment*
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2866064

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer 11 no longer supports these Group Policy settings:

- Turn on Internet Explorer 7 Standards Mode
- Turn off Compatibility View button
- Turn off Quick Tabs functionality
- Turn off the quick pick menu
- Use large icons for command buttons

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321453.aspx

Comment: Utterly retarded that they do this crap.

Answer (score 1):

The GPO method mentioned everywhere on the internet didn’t work for me.  It seems to be stored in the registry as binary.  It took a little bit of testing but I found the phrase that I used for testing located in the registry at:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData\UserFilter

I can successfully export the key and data from one systems and import it into another and it works.  Not sure about appending it to existing data though, still working on that one...??

Comment: Wait, so are you confirming that compatibility view settings can be tweaked/changed in IE11 then?

Comment: Yes (technically), but I didn't decipher the code for it.  Seems that it is a binary thing in the registry, and there is a "counter" that goes along with it (the counter increments the more sites you have in the view settings list)