# Possible to automate setting of Internet Explorer settings?

Tags: windows-7, script, internet-explorer, powershell, automation

Is it possible to automate the setting of some Internet Explorer settings through some sort of self-contained script or program (and not something like Group Policy or domain controlling)?

In particular, I'm wondering if a site can be added to the "Compatibility View settings", "Trusted Sites", and if popups can be set to load into new tabs (rather than separate popup windows).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve all of this via group policy.

Navigate to:

```
User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> 
Windows Components -> Internet Explorer
```

Here is an example of changing the popup behaviour:

[image]

There are many options, you can read about more configuration [here](http://www.concurrency.com/infrastructure/customize-ie8-through-group-policy/).

To do this via a script, you can edit these directly in the registry via VBS or powershell.

See: [Registry setting for IE's compatibility view settings to add a site?](https://superuser.com/questions/629918/registry-setting-for-ies-compatibility-view-settings-to-add-a-site)